# how to use FOSUSERBUNDLE and MEMCACHED?

Tags: php, symfony, session, memcached, fosuserbundle

I injected the services.yml like that

```
services:
    memcache:
        class: Memcache
        calls:
            - [ addServer, [ %session_memcached_host%, %session_memcached_port% ]]  
    session.handler.memcache:
            class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcacheSessionHandler
            arguments: [@memcache]
```

and my config.yml

```
handler_id: session.handler.memcache
```

and my php.ini

```
    extension="memcache.so"
    session.save_handler= memcache

    session.save_path= tcp://127.0.0.1:11211
```

and i installed memcached using this [link](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/Install) 
but the problem when i load fosbundle login page i get this error

```
Attempted to load class "Memcache" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to integrate symfony with memcached is to use an existing bundle. I use leaseweb/memcache-bundle and it's super simple - just follow the instructions here: https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswMemcacheBundle. And remember to start memcached first ;)

Yet to integrate this fully with FOSUserBundle, however it does support php sessions.